# How to connect a motion sensor to FPGA?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, fpga, verilog

I am currently using a RealDigital Blackboard FPGA and wanted to know if it is possible to connect an FIR motion sensor to it. The link to the website with the FPGA schematics is here: https://www.realdigital.org/hardware/blackboard
Looking at the board, there are only a few pins for servo motor control, however, I'm pretty sure those can't be used to program sensors. There are also 3 PMOD connectors (each 2x6) which I think can be used to achieve my goal, however, I'm not 100% sure. I already have a 3-pin motion sensor at home that I got from Amazon ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07GJDJV63/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GJDJV63)), however, I am unsure if it is possible to connect this specific motion sensor to any PMOD port. If it is not possible would I have to buy a motion sensor specifically for PMOD's? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.sunrom.com/p/micro-pir-motion-detection-sensor-am312

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motion sensor you have uses 3 pins, 2 for power, one as an output signal that remains low when it doesn't detect motion and is set to high for a few seconds if it detects motion.

All you need is to connect the sensor to the appropriate input voltage and ground, then connect the signal (labeled as "out") pin to a GPIO (general purpose IO) pin on your FPGA.

If you look at the board schematic, the PMOD pins can also be used as GPIO, so you're good to go.